# hide element when clicked anywhere on the page and show it by click on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have an input text which i used for quick search, under this input there is a div which i use to show search result. by typing in input, the result is showing up in div.now i want to hide this element (meaning div) whenever i click on window and show it again by click on the input.I tried few jquery code to hide the element but i could not show it again.

```
$(window).click(function () {
    $('#livesearch').hide();
});
$('#search').click(function () {
    $('#livesearch').show();
});
```

Comment: Show the full code + HTML. The code you pasted is valid.

Comment: Have you tried putting `e.stopPropagation` in your `#search` click handler? I don't know if it'll work, but it might.

Comment: i have no idea how to use e.stopPropagation

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `blur()` and `focus()` event trigger of jQuery.
[doc](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

```
$('#input_window').blur(function () {
  $('#livesearch').hide();
}).focus(function () {
  $('#livesearch').show();
});
```

Change the `#input_window` to whatever in your html code.

Comment: now when i click on search result, div`s element hide first(the search result are links to other page)

Comment: That's the intended behavior of `blur()` when you clicked the result links, you have **blurred** away from your input box. I guess what you want is to only blur when a user lose focus on both input box and the search result. I suggest put this two elements in one `div` and bind `blur()` event with this div.

Comment: I put them in one div but i don`t know how to use bind.(my Knowledge about the jquery is very low)

Comment: Saying your have `<div id="input_plus_result">...</div>`, you modify my code `$('#input_window').blur()...` to `$('#input_plus_result').blur()...` Hope it helps.

Comment: I did do that, but nothing happened.. the search result didn`t hide or show.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure a click event exists for the "window" object. But I am no expert in JS for that matter.

Please check this code, I think it does what you want to achieve in a bit different way.

---

Edit:
Please check this code. This prevents the search results from hiding if you click them. Since I am already studying JQuery I took the time to experiment with this, achieving this functionality feels more complex than it should be :)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(':not(.search_result)').focus(function () {
            $('#livesearch').hide();
        });
        $('#search').focus(function () {
            $('#livesearch').show();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input id='search' type="text" />
    <div id='livesearch' style='display: none'>
        <ul>
            <li><a class='search_result' href='#'>result#1</a></li>
            <li><a class='search_result' href='#'>result#2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    The rest of the page.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this code, it`s have the same problem as @steven.yang code

Comment: It didn`t work for me. the search result show up but they are not going to hide again. i also change first focus to blur, and once again didn`t work!

Comment: Yeah... it works with IE9.0 if you allow it to run the scripts. Didn't work with FF or Chrome :(